# Refactor for optimal Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have this piece of validation code and do not think its in the spirit of good Kotlin,

In this code I compare to Data Classes content **networker: Networker** and **worker: Networker**

```
    if (networker.name != worker.name && networker.name != null) {
        worker.name = networker.name
    }
    if (networker.lastName != worker.lastName && networker.lastName != null) {
        worker.lastName = networker.lastName
    }
    if (networker.phone != worker.phone && networker.phone != null) {
        worker.phone = networker.phone
    }
    if (networker.email != worker.email && networker.email != null) {
        worker.email = networker.email
    }
```

How can I improve this with better & more elegant Kotlin code please

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If elegance is your main concern here, then you could write it this way.

```
worker.name = networker.name ?: worker.name
worker.lastName = networker.lastName ?: worker.lastName
worker.phone = networker.phone ?: worker.phone
worker.email = networker.email ?: worker.email
```

This acheives the same result as your code (copy values from networker to worker, except nulls), but I think it looks nicer.

Answer (score 2):

Since following conditional assignment is pointless

```
if (X != Y) {
    Y = X
}
```

as without this check the result of assignment would be same, you can omit it and only keep null-check via `.let {}`

```
networker.name?.let { worker.name = it }
networker.lastName?.let { worker.lastName = it }
networker.phone?.let { worker.phone = it }
networker.email?.let { worker.email = it }
```

Comment: I am comparing the two classes because the one might have changed, it is as important to see if it changed as it is to see if the new field is null

**Background:** I am getting the changed (or not) class from a spring/thymeleaf HTML with a doAjaxPost() or js script but the fields not in the HTML form get set to null and overwrite the data set when I persist it, with my test above I copy only the changed data after testing for change and null to the original data then persist it to preserve the other fields not used in the HTML. I guess you are correct the change test is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the low-level improvements addressed in other answers, I'd also consider *where* you put this code.

Since all these lines are accomplishing a single task — updating one object from another — it would make sense to bundle them into a function; not only does that clearly associate them, it also lets you give them a descriptive name.

The obvious place for that would be inside the data class itself; perhaps a method called `updateFrom(other: Networker)` which updates the object it's called on.  That would make it obvious to the caller which object was being mutated.

Sometimes you want to keep data classes as simple data holders, though, or don't have control over them.  In that case, it could be an extension function.

Comment: Interesting Idea, I like to do it but have not enough experience to implement it yet, Can you point me to sample/lesson some ware